# How to get Audio recording buffer data live?

Tags: ios, swift, audio-streaming

I am working on get audio data from iPhone mic and send it to socket, I already try AVAudioEngine to get audio buffer but some how its not woking. so can you please suggest me what it better way to get recording buffer data in live.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        // initialize engine
        engine = AVAudioEngine()
        guard nil != engine?.inputNode else {
            // @TODO: error out
            return
        }



        SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.socket.on("listen") {data, ack in

            let BuffurData:Data = data[0] as! Data

            // let playData = self?.audioBufferToNSData(PCMBuffer: BuffurData as! AVAudioPCMBuffer)
            do {
               // let data = NSData(bytes: &BuffurData, length: BuffurData.count)

                let player = try AVAudioPlayer(data:BuffurData)
                player.play()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.description)
            }



            print("socket connected \(data)")
        }
    }

 func installTap() {

        engine = AVAudioEngine()
        guard let engine = engine, let input = engine.inputNode else {
            // @TODO: error out
            return
        }

        let format = input.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
        input.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize:4096, format:format, block: { [weak self] buffer, when in

            guard let this = self else {
                return
            }

            // writing to file: for testing purposes only
            do {
                try this.file!.write(from: buffer)
            } catch {

            }

            if let channel1Buffer = buffer.floatChannelData?[0] {
               let test = self?.copyAudioBufferBytes(buffer)
                let stram = self?.toNSData(PCMBuffer: buffer)
                SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.socket.emit("talk",stram!);

               // socket.on("listen", function (data)



                /*! @property floatChannelData
                 @abstract Access the buffer's float audio samples.
                 @discussion
                 floatChannelData returns pointers to the buffer's audio samples if the buffer's format is
                 32-bit float, or nil if it is another format.

                 The returned pointer is to format.channelCount pointers to float. Each of these pointers
                 is to "frameLength" valid samples, which are spaced by "stride" samples.

                 If format.interleaved is false (as with the standard deinterleaved float format), then
                 the pointers will be to separate chunks of memory. "stride" is 1.

                 If format.interleaved is true, then the pointers will refer into the same chunk of interleaved
                 samples, each offset by 1 frame. "stride" is the number of interleaved channels.
                 */

                // @TODO: send data, better to pass into separate queue for processing
            }            
        })

        engine.prepare()

        do {
            try engine.start()
        } catch {
            // @TODO: error out
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem with AVAudioEngine?

Comment: See my update code, I wish I convert buffer to data and send to socket, When I get some data via socket I am not able to play it. see viewDidLoad function, I am try to playing it from socket response.

Comment: you should use the AVAudioPlayerNode for playing buffer. First, you convert the data into a buffer then play it.

Comment: self.audioPlayer.scheduleBuffer(pcmBuffer, completionHandler: nil), self.audioPlayer.play()

Comment: can you please provide more information about to how to play

Comment: you are sending NSData and play the Data, please play the NSdata too.

Comment: I also found that I m not able to play audio directly from Install tapped method

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: is installTap correct method ? to get audio data ?

Comment: is my answer helpful for you?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var audioPlayerQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "audioPlayerQueue", qos: DispatchQoS.userInteractive)

var peerAudioPlayer: AVAudioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
var peerInputFormat: AVAudioFormat?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // initialize engine
    engine = AVAudioEngine()
    guard nil != engine?.inputNode else {
        // @TODO: error out
        return
    }
    engine.attach(self.peerAudioPlayer)
    self.peerInputFormat = AVAudioFormat.init(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 1, interleaved: false)
    self.peerAudioEngine.connect(peerAudioPlayer, to: self.peerAudioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: peerInput?.outputFormat(forBus: 0))
    do {
        peerAudioEngine.prepare()
        try peerAudioEngine.start()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.socket.on("listen") { data, ack in
        let pcmBuffer = toPCMBuffer(data: data)
        self.audioPlayerQueue.async {
            self.peerAudioPlayer.scheduleBuffer(pcmBuffer, completionHandler: nil)
            if self.peerAudioEngine.isRunning {
                self.peerAudioPlayer.play()
            } else {
                do {
                    try self.peerAudioEngine.start()
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    print("socket connected \(data)")
}       

func toPCMBuffer(data: NSData) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer {
    let audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 1, interleaved: false)  // given NSData audio format
    let PCMBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity: UInt32(data.length) / audioFormat.streamDescription.pointee.mBytesPerFrame)
    PCMBuffer.frameLength = PCMBuffer.frameCapacity
    let channels = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: PCMBuffer.floatChannelData, count: Int(PCMBuffer.format.channelCount))
    data.getBytes(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(channels[0]) , length: data.length)
    return PCMBuffer
}

func installTap() {    
    engine = AVAudioEngine()
    guard let engine = engine, let input = engine.inputNode else {
        // @TODO: error out
        return
    }

    let format = input.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
    input.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 4410, format: format, block: { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, AVAudioTime) in
        guard let this = self else {
            return
        }
        let stram = self?.toNSData(PCMBuffer: buffer)
        SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.socket.emit("talk",stram!)
    })

    do {    
        engine.prepare()
        try engine.start()
    } catch {
        // @TODO: error out
    }
}

// **Edit: For Enable Lound Speaker**

func speakerEnabled(_ enabled:Bool) -> Bool {
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    var options = session.categoryOptions

    if (enabled) {
        options.insert(.defaultToSpeaker)
    } else {
        options.remove(.defaultToSpeaker)
    }

    try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: options)
    return true
}
```

Comment: What is peerInput in it ?

Comment: Yes but it crash in  self.peerAudioPlayer.play(), Got message "required condition is false: _engine != nil"

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to get mic audio buffer ?

Comment: @DipenChudasama Check my edited answer for install tap function

Comment: Yes, Working now, But please suggest me how to set audio input format for pcm16bit.

Comment: Please use this format:             self.peerInputFormat = AVAudioFormat.init(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 1, interleaved: false) @DipenChudasama

Comment: Yes, But not able to set 16bit in it, I also need to play audio in speaker can you please help me ?, Currently it is play in phone call speaker.

Comment: Not playing sound in speaker. Because I play peerAudio player, so may be I need to add some settings on it.

Comment: @DipenChudasama Add this in speakerEnabled method :            try! session.setActive(true)

Comment: Facing Crash with message " reason: 'required condition is false: IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(format"

Comment: Are you creating two seperate object for AVAudioEngine? i.e peerAudioEngine and engine